# Python: recursive method rollbacks changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, recursion

So I got stuck on something like this (a simplified version)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left= None
        self.cost = 0

    def change(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.cost=self.cost+1
            self.left.change

data=[]
for i in range(10):
    data.append(Node())
    if i>0:
        data[i].left = data[i-1]

data[8].change()
print(data[2].cost) #0
```

I want `data[2].cost` to have changed, but it rollbacks. Can I make it works without skipping recursion? (In full version I actually keep a two-dimensional array of nodes that have four pointers, so making an iteration suck.)

Comment: `self.left.change` does _not_ recurse. It doesn't call the function

Comment: Is this `self.left.change` supposed to be `self.left.change()`?

Comment: I'm not sure this question will be of much benefit for future readers. Maybe OP may delete it ?

Comment: @rrter123 No, it just means you're human.  I once spent more time than I'd like to admit searching for a bug where I had looped on `i` but indexed with `j`.

Comment: @pjs and in my actual problem I did x instead of self.x.
The happy life of the programmer. Do you think I should delete this ask?

Comment: @rrter123 I'm not sure you could delete it at this point, given that there is an upvoted answer.  Meanwhile, you got a small bump from it.  Even if you can delete it, it's a judgement call on your part.  I don't think it's compelling either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `()` when you call your `change` method.

```
def change(self):
    if self.left is not None:
        self.left.cost=self.cost+1
        self.left.change()
```

output:

> 6

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want to call change but you didn't. You just refered to the function object and did nothing with it.

Just change `self.left.change` to `self.left.change()` to call it